# Metatag keywords in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, search-engine

I'm running a website with 3 domains redirecting to that domain (without a index file, just by admin panel at the provider). Is there a way to SEO these redirecting domains? When I was thinking about this I realized that by redirecting you probably can't upload a .htaccess because you don't have webspace.

I think it's not possible, but i ask is just to be sure.

Comment: `meta` keywords are quite useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - it's not possible to SEO a domain that simply redirects to a different domain.

Meta tags / data won't get you any SEO benefit anyway - it's all about content and authority.

Comment: I know that, but I think a domainname is also crucial for example: when your domain name contains "computer service" it will be more important then a domain name containing. "fluffy bunny" with the exact same content.

Comment: The domain name doesn't mean anything if there's no content *on that domain*